# Draw along a path detection in iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am writing a writing app for Kids.
I need to enforce writing along a define path like in Dora ABC apps. For example, writing A.

When user touch and draw, it draw only when user finger are along the defined path and can detect whether user follow that path or not.

My path are defined in `UIBezierpath`.

I try to use `CGRectContainsPoint` but it seem to be too much code when I have so many alphabet.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "I try to use CGRectContainsPoint but it seem to be too much code when I have so many alphabeth." Can you clarify what you mean here? You just don't like how long the function name is? Does it do what you want?

Comment: Hi, I am not really sure how to proceed. My clue is CGRectContainsPoint but i think it is ok for rectangle or other regular shape but for combination of shape, it's too complicated. Or maybe i don't know how to use it properly. For example, letter A is combination of shape right? Please look at the sample image http://veayo.com/IMG_0078.PNG

Answer (score 2):

you may try another approach-

Using Custom gestures in ios: Using this feature you can have predefined gestures for alphabets and you can use these gestures  for detection. demo code  available at https://github.com/britg/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS
Or if you want to implement it from scratch- http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2012/01/31/creating-custom-gesture-recognisers-for-ios/

Comment: Yes, I also use MultistrokGestureRecognizer in my project for scoring user gesture. But still I need to show user progress. like [here](http://veayo.com/IMG_0078.PNG). Your custom-gesture recognizer idea gave me some new light to search for another solution. Pattern detection like android keylock code